# How do I only copy files to a destination that exist in the folder from the source, everything else should not be copied

Tags: files, rsync

How can I copy files from source to destination, where in all the files existing in destination (with directory structure), only should be copied from the source, overwritten in the destination. Rest of the files (including the directory structure) should not be copied from source to destination. I think `rsync` can achieve this, not sure on the options we have to select.

Comment: You only want to copy files `--existing` on the target? Hm, should be possible . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Dubu I didn't know that flag existed. Here's an example:

```
$ ls -R src ; ls -R dst
src:
a  b  c  empty_dir  sub_dir

src/empty_dir:

src/sub_dir:
e  f
dst:
a  c  sub_dir

dst/sub_dir:
f
$ rsync --recursive --existing --verbose src/ dst
sending incremental file list
a
c
sub_dir/f

sent 262 bytes  received 71 bytes  666.00 bytes/sec
```

Answer (score -1):

Go for "rsync"
Use it as,
"rsync source destination" it's same as you use command "cp".

Comment: Can you provide a working example?